# How to extract the last value before last : character but after the last comma?

Tags: string, parsing, clojure, jvm

I'm using Clojure to parse and analyze XML files.
Here is a sample:

```
BSS:17,NSVC:1
BSS:17,NSVC:4
BSS:17,NSVC:5
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:3
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:4
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:5
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:0
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:1
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:2
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:3
```

I'm interested in that last value (a value after the last comma but before the last : , NSVS and BTS in my case), digits after them don't matter.
How to extract that last value in the previous strings?

Comment: If your names/values are always [A-Z] and [0-9] this is a pretty simple regexp: `(A-Z)+:[0-9]+$`

Comment: @Alex (re-seq #"(A-Z)+:[0-9]+$" "BSS:17,BTSM:14,BTS:4")  returns nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function to process the individual lines:

```
(defn lastval [s]
  (second (re-find #",([^,:]+):\d*$" s)))
                 ;   ^ the comma preceding the interesting section
                 ;    ^ the part in parens will be captured as a group
                 ;     ^ character class meaning "anything except , or :"
                 ;            ^ the colon after the interesting section
                 ;             ^ any number of digits after the colon
                 ;                ^ end of string
          ; ^ returns a vector of [part-that-matches, first-group];
          ;   we're interested in the latter, hence second
```

NB. this returns `nil` if the regex doesn't match.

E.g.:

```
user> (lastval "BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:3")
"BTS"
```

If you later want to extract all the information in easy-to-work-with bits, you can use

```
(defn parse [s]
  (map (juxt second #(nth % 2)) (re-seq #"(?:^|,)([^,:]+):(\d+)" s)))
```

E.g.

```
user> (parse "BSS:17,BTS:0,BTS:3")
(["BSS" "17"] ["BTS" "0"] ["BTS" "3"])
```

Comment: If I'm going to work with Clojure developer, I wish I can work with you. World class code. First time I read about juxt function. Thank you.

Comment: You used re-find, why you didn't use re-seq?

Comment: Happy to help! I think you will find that this kind of code is quite commonplace in Clojure. :-) As for your question: `re-find` returns just one match, if any (if you pass it a regex and a string, the first one; if you pass in a `Matcher` object, the "next" one; e.g. try `(let [m (re-matcher #"(foo|bar)" "foobar")] [(re-find m) (re-find m)])`). `re-seq` returns a seq of all matches. Since in the `lastval` function we only expect a single match, `re-find` is the right tool for the job. Note that `parse` above does indeed use `re-seq`, since it does need to allow for multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [lastIndexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) to find the last comma?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
(def tmp (str "BSS:17,NSVC:1\n
BSS:17,NSVC:4\n
BSS:17,NSVC:5\n
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:3\n
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:4\n
BSS:17,BTSM:0,BTS:5\n
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:0\n
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:1\n
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:2\n
BSS:17,BTSM:1,BTS:3\n"))


(defn split [s sep]
  (->> (.split s sep)
       seq
       (filter #(not (empty? %)))))

(reduce (fn[h v]
          (conj h (last v)))

          [] (map #(split % ",")
                  (split tmp "\n")))
```

I am assuming there is some sort of delimeter between the lines.